# Open source PTP

Tags: c#, time

I am looking to do some synchronization between a couple of computers and a master "clock"-computer, which could be done by using NTP, but it is not precise enough for me. Therefore I have been looking at the Precision Time Protocol (PTP), but does there exist any C# open source implementation of the PTP?

Comment: I'd tend to invoke an external program that does the synchronization instead of trying to do it from your program.

Comment: I am sorry, I have edited the question. The idea was of course to have one master server which could synchronize the clocks between the other computers.

Comment: I don't know of any opensource implementation of PTP in C# :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer the question. It doesn't seem like there is an open source implementation of PTP in C#.